# Parsing through each folder to pull in information in python

Tags: python, pandas, opencsv

I have a directory with a folder for each customer. In each customer folder there is a csv file named `surveys.csv`. I want to open each customer folder and then pull the data from the csv and concatenate. I also want to create a column with that customer id which is the name of the folder.

```
import os
rootdir = '../data/customer_data/'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(mycsvdir, 'surveys.csv'))

        # loop through the files and read them in with pandas
        dataframes = []  # a list to hold all the individual pandas DataFrames
        for csvfile in csvfiles:
            df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
            df['patient_id'] = os.path.dirname
            dataframes.append(df)
            
# concatenate them all together
result = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
result.head()
```

This code is only giving me a dataframe with one customer's data. In the directory : '../data/customer_data/' there should be about 25 folders with customer data. I want to concatenate all the 25 of the `surveys.csv` files into a dataframe. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Put this line:

```py
dataframes = []
```

Outside the outer for loop.

It erases the list every loop.

Another issues:

- In this line `csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(mycsvdir, 'surveys.csv'))` - use `subdir` to get full path of the files.
- `csvfiles` is only one file - why do you use loop to read it?

Comment: it still is showing only the last file. I am thinking maybe I am not paring through the folders properly?

Comment: What is `mycsvdir`?